# Is webview better than recycler view in term's of scrolling content and display comparison?

Tags: android, webview, android-recyclerview

I am beginner in android development with a good background in web development my question is web view better for viewing content multiple content from server since its the server site being loaded or is it best to load the resources and use recycle view to display content and in doing dose it perform well since it uses java code only to run the application

Answer (score 0):

Performance is not directly comparable, loading a `hello world` on a `Webview` can be more performative than loading one million items with high res photo.

For the sake of your question, I will risk saying:

`RecyclerView` should always be the preferred choice, not because is completely working on the platform language, but because the `RecyclerView` has been improved to be performant.

The `RecyclerView` use a `RecyclerView.Adapter` to create a list. The inner working of it literally recycles the rows from a `View` pool (hence the naming). This means, that the memory will only hold the enough `views` to fit the UI needs.

Inside the adapter, there are 2 methods: one for the creation and one for combining the row view with the data at that index. The creation is only executed if it is needed, but the combination of the data with the layout is always executed. You can confirm that by adding a log on each.

That been explained, it could be a deeper confusion. Getting data for the `WebView` and for the `RecyclerView.Adapter` are two completely different approaches:

- For the `WebView` simply pass a `String` containing an url.
- For the adapter, the preferred method is an HTTP request to an API REST.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest you can't compare these two even a bit. They are both made for completely different use cases:

**WebView** should display some web content provided by a web server or some locally stored html files. The performance you are asking for is highly dependent on the actual data you want to display. In addition the whole look and feel (UI/UX of the actual displayed content) has to be implemented in html/js etc.

**RecyclerView** was designed with the aim to display big sets of data (since a simple ListView was not flexible and performant enough). It does not define the actual way the data is displayed (you can use different LayoutManagers or even define your own). The main idea is to load the data from an Adapter that really has to be displayed now (with a bit of buffer before and behind currently visible area on the screen).

**Conclusion:** you can't compare them, especially in terms of performance since they both do absolutely different things. If you have your data as web content (html files, website etc.) then simply use a WebView. If you have a large set of data (from whatever source) and want to display this data in a way the app is staying smooth and responsive (especially scrolling), take RecyclerView.